# Deploy jar on a remote server via Jenkins

Tags: scala, jenkins, deployment, jar, continuous-integration

I have an akka-scala app that I'm able to build as a jar. I can then send the jar to a remote server via Jenkins. However, I don't know how to properly deploy the app.

The first problem is killing previous instances of my app. If in Jenkins I try to execute such commands as `pkill -f %proc%` or `ps ax | grep ... | awk ... | xargs kill -9` via ssh, Jenkins finishes with return code -1 even if I add `|| true` to the end of these commands.

The second problem is starting the app. I'm able to successfully run the jar with `nohup java -jar ... &` command, but it doesn't really start though I'm able to see it in the process list.

**None of these problems occur if I execute commands manually (even via ssh)**.

My question is - what am I doing wrong? What is the proper way to perform such task? Am I using the wrong tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [something like supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) for starting/stoping your app and also restarting it in case of crash or server reboot.

Comment: After tinkering with supervisord settings I was able to successfully deploy my app using single Jenkins stage. Thank you for your advice.